# Error when trying to build Fastify-Zod validation schema

Tags: typescript, fastify, zod

I am new to the typescript ecosystem. I am trying to use zod to validate my fastify request/response, but I am not able to build the schemas using `fastify-zod` plugin as it throws a compile error. This is my `user.schema.ts`

```
import { z } from 'zod'
import { buildJsonSchemas } from 'fastify-zod';

export enum Role {
    Agent = 'Agent',
    Admin = 'Admin',
}

const createUserSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string({
        required_error: "Email is required",
        invalid_type_error: "Email must be a string"
    }).email(),
    role: z.nativeEnum(Role, {
        required_error: "Role is required"
    }),
    teamId: z.number({
        required_error: "Team id is required"
    })
});

export type CreateUserInput = z.infer<typeof createUserSchema>;

export const { schemas: userSchemas, $ref } = buildJsonSchemas({
    createUserSchema     //error here (compile)
});
```

I am getting an error at `createUserSchema` and this is the error:

```
(property) createUserSchema: z.ZodObject<{
    email: z.ZodString;
    role: z.ZodNativeEnum<typeof Role>;
    teamId: z.ZodNumber;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    email: string;
    role: Role;
    teamId: number;
}, {
    email: string;
    role: Role;
    teamId: number;
}>
Property 'brand' is missing in type 'ZodObject<{ email: ZodString; role: ZodNativeEnum<typeof Role>; teamId: ZodNumber; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { email: string; role: Role; teamId: number; }, { ...; }>' but required in type 'ZodType<unknown, ZodTypeDef, unknown>'.ts(2741)
    types.d.ts(78, 5): 'brand' is declared here.
    Models.d.ts(2, 59): The expected type comes from property 'createUserSchema' which is declared here on type 'Models<string>'
```

No idea where I am getting this from:

> Property 'brand' is missing in type

Any idea what I maybe missing here?

**Edit:**

This is my package.json dependency

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.7.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "fastify": "^4.6.0",
    "fastify-cors": "^6.1.0",
    "fastify-zod": "^1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1",
    "zod": "3.18.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.2"
  },
```

I updated the zod version to 3.18.0 from 3.17.2 and I am getting:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)
```

Comment: Do you have the most recent versions of the packages and typings? The code seems fine in a playground: https://tsplay.dev/WJ52km

Comment: @Oblosys I updated zod version to 3.18.0 from 3.17.0 and now I am getting this error: `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)`

Comment: Hmm, hard to say. Maybe you're using a TypeScript version lower than 4.1? The playground code only works from v4.1.5 to v4.8.3.

Comment: @Oblosys Ts version is `4.8.2`

Comment: Ah wait, `npm info` shows the latest zod version is not 3.18.0 but 3.19.1. Version 3.18.0 indeed yields a possibly-infinite instantiation error, but 3.19.1 works fine.

Comment: @Oblosys that resolved the issue! Can you please go ahead and write that as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `zod` together with `fastify-zod`, outdated package versions can cause a few obscure errors.

Combining `zod@3.17.0` and `fastify-zod@1.2.0` may yield errors mentioning missing `'brand'` properties:

```
Property 'brand' is missing in type 'ZodObject; teamId: ZodNumber; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { email: string; role: Role; teamId: number; }, { ...; }>' but required in type 'ZodType'.ts(2741)
    types.d.ts(78, 5): 'brand' is declared here.
    Models.d.ts(2, 59): The expected type comes from property 'createUserSchema' which is declared here on type 'Models'
```

Using `zod@3.18.0` and `fastify-zod@1.2.0`, or having a TypeScript version lower than v4.1, may yield excessively-deep instantiation errors:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)
```

With the latest versions of both packages (currently `zod@3.19.1` and `fastify-zod@1.2.0`), everything works as expected.

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkKr9W)